# Rule for amount of facts

Tags: prolog

For a school project I want to make a planning maker in Prolog. I want Prolog to make a planning for every day. On each day a certain amount of employees are needed and employees can only work on certain days. I want Prolog to make a planning that plans the right amount of people on each day. For that I wrote the following code:

```
workingday_employeesneeded(monday, 2).
workingday_employeesneeded(tuesday, 1).
workingday_employeesneeded(wednesday, 2).

employee_availability(tom, monday).
employee_availability(thomas, monday).
employee_availability(timme, monday).
employee_availability(timo, monday).
employee_availability(tom, tuesday).

planning(Employee, Day) :-
    workingday_employeesneeded(Day, Amount),
    employee_availability(Employee, Day).

planning(Employee, Day) :-
    aggregate_all(count, planning(Employee, Day), Count),
    workingday_employeesneeded(Day, Amount),
    Count <= Amount.
```

However, I can't get Prolog to give me the right result, as I query the following Prolog gives me all the options, not regarding the amount of employees needed.

```
?- planning(X, Y).

X = tom,
Y = monday ;
X = thomas,
Y = monday ;
X = timme,
Y = monday ;
X = timo,
Y = monday ;
X = tom,
Y = tuesday ;
false.
```

Can you guy's see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I thought it might be handy to make a list of employees for each day in the planning. So I edited the code to the following (also fixing some syntax errors pointed out in the comments);

```
planning_on_day(Day, Employees) :-
    workingday_employeesneeded(Day, Amount),
    findall(E, employee_availability(E, Day), Employees),
    length(Employees, Amount).
```

The following problem still exists; if there are more employees available than needed the program does not print the planning for that day instead of only picking the first N employees.

Do you guys have suggestions to fix that problem?

Comment: Two independent rules for `planing/2`?

Comment: Also, `<=` must be written `=<`.

Comment: Which answers do you expect of `?- planning_on_day(monday, Xs).` ?

Comment: @repeat I expect ```Xs = [tom, thomas];```

Comment: Any more answers? What about permutations?

Comment: At this point I don't care about the possibilities as long as the amount is correct, so for example ```Xs = [thomas, timme]; Xs = [tom, timme]; enz``` is also correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply your predicate fails because first you use `findall/3` then you constraint the length of the list. For instance, for `monday` there are 4 employees available, you find all of them with `findall/3` and store into `Employees`. Then you check the lenght of the list and it fails. To solve it you need find all the available employees and then find a subset of the list with desired length. So your code will be:

```
subset([], []).
subset([E|Tail], [E|NTail]):-
  subset(Tail, NTail).
subset([_|Tail], NTail):-
  subset(Tail, NTail).

planning_on_day(Day, Employees) :-
    workingday_employeesneeded(Day, Amount),
    findall(E, employee_availability(E, Day), E),
    length(Employees,Amount),
    subset(E,Employees).

?- planning_on_day(monday,P).
P = [tom, thomas]
P = [tom, timme]
P = [tom, timo]
P = [thomas, timme]
P = [thomas, timo]
P = [timme, timo]
false

?- planning_on_day(tuesday,P).
P = [tom]
false

?- planning_on_day(wednesday,P).
false
```

Then, if you want find the plan of the week you can add:

```
isDifferent(_, []).
isDifferent(X, [H | T]) :-
  X \= H,
  isDifferent(X, T).

allDifferent([]).
allDifferent([H | T]) :-
  isDifferent(H, T),
  allDifferent(T).

solve([],Plan,Plan):-
    flatten(Plan,P),
    allDifferent(P).
solve([Day|T],LT,Plan):-
    workingday_employeesneeded(Day, Amount),
    planning_on_day(Day,PlanD),
    length(A,Amount),
    subset(PlanD,A),
    append(LT,[PlanD],LT1),
    solve(T,LT1,Plan).

?- solve([monday,tuesday],[],L).
L = [[thomas, timme], [tom]]
L = [[thomas, timo], [tom]]
L = [[timme, timo], [tom]]
```